# Is there any difference in the implementation of APNS on iOS 4 and iOS 5?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Is there any difference in the push Notification implementation on different ios versions like ios 4, ios 5?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I can see in the [iOS 4.3 to iOS 4.0 API Diffs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/iOS50APIDiff/index.html).

Want to expand on your question?

Comment: where exactly it is mentioned?

Comment: That page documents the changes in iOS API's between versions, there appears to be no difference between iOS 4.3 and iOS 5. Maybe if you shared what you are looking for, somebody could help more.

Comment: I need the way push notification appears in ios 4, ios5, and ios6. For that i am saking are there any programmmatically or APIs changes?